# Display blank instead of #NUM! error code

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

```
{=IF(ROWS(A$9:A223)<=A$1,INDEX(Tracker!A:A,SMALL(IF(Tracker!$R$3:$R$9610=A$2,ROW(Tracker!$A$3:$A$9610)),ROWS(A$9:A223))),"")}
```

I need the `#NUM!` not to show up. I can't figure out where the , `""` goes. The function above is what I have so far. It is an Array. By the way, this works just fine. I just can't have the `#NUM!` showing up because `count`.... anything doesn't count it right. And what's up with `Count` counting the formulas in cells too?! Sorry, first question only. Thank you everyone!

Comment: Use `IFERROR` like this: `=IFERROR(IF(ROWS(A$9:A223)<=A$1,INDEX(Tracker!A:A,SMALL(IF(Tracker!$R$3:$R$9610=A$2,ROW(Tracker!$A$3:$A$9610)),ROWS(A$9:A223))),""),"")`

Comment: Btw, `COUNT` only counts numbers (which includes dates since it is represented in Excel as numbers). Not text or blanks or `""` resulting from formula.

Comment: You are Awesome! Thank you! Where can I give you credit?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting as answer from comments:

Use `IFERROR` like this:

`=IFERROR(IF(ROWS(A$9:A223)<=A$1,INDEX(Tracker!A:A,SMALL(IF(Tracker!$R$3:$R$9610‌​=A$2,ROW(Tracker!$A$3:$A$9610)),ROWS(A$9:A223))),""),"")`

HTH.